# Python: Extract CSVs of time series data from high-resolution netCDF data using xarray

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

Trying to load several high-resolution netCDF files using OpenDAP and xarray into a single dataset; and then extract time series data by latitude-longitude coordinates to individual CSV files. I am using `xarray` and `dask`.

I can write a single CSV, but looping through the entire dataset will take >1200 hours.

**Is it better to select individual points or all points and then convert all to CSV files?**

```py
import xarray as xr


Variables = collections.namedtuple('Variables', ['new_name', 'conversion', 'units'])
toMJm2 = 3.6e-3
toDegC = 273.15
tomm = 1.0

VARS_DICT = {"rsds": Variables('SRAD', toMJm2, "MJ m**-2"),
             "tasmax": Variables("TMax", toDegC, "C"),
             "tasmin": Variables("TMin", toDegC, "C"),
             "pr": Variables("Rain", tomm, "mm")}


def open_rename_ds(file):
    ds = xr.open_dataset(file, chunks={"lat": 5, "lon": 10, "time": -1})
    ds = ds.squeeze('crs').drop('crs')
    ds = ds.assign_coords(lon=(((ds.lon + 180) % 360) - 180))
    var_name = os.path.basename(file).split("_")[2]
    v = VARS_DICT[var_name]
    for k in ds.data_vars:
        if v.conversion == 273.15:
            ds[v.new_name] = ds[k] - v.conversion
        else:
            ds[v.new_name] = ds[k] * v.conversion
        ds[v.new_name].attrs["units"] = v.units
    _ds = ds.drop([k])
    return _ds.sel(time=slice("2020-01-01","2099-12-30"))

fileslist = ['http://thredds.northwestknowledge.net:8080/thredds/dodsC/agg_macav2metdata_tasmax_bcc-csm1-1_r1i1p1_rcp85_2006_2099_CONUS_daily.nc',
'http://thredds.northwestknowledge.net:8080/thredds/dodsC/agg_macav2metdata_tasmin_bcc-csm1-1_r1i1p1_rcp85_2006_2099_CONUS_daily.nc', 'http://thredds.northwestknowledge.net:8080/thredds/dodsC/agg_macav2metdata_pr_bcc-csm1-1_r1i1p1_rcp85_2006_2099_CONUS_daily.nc', 'http://thredds.northwestknowledge.net:8080/thredds/dodsC/agg_macav2metdata_rsds_bcc-csm1-1_r1i1p1_rcp85_2006_2099_CONUS_daily.nc']

dss = [open_rename_ds(file) for file in fileslist]
# Create a single dataset for the four opened datasets using `.update`
ds = dss[0]
for d in dss[1:]:
    ds.update(d)

# drop the attributes for brevity
ds.attrs = {}
```

Here is the size and information on the dataset:

```py
print("ds size in GB {:0.2f}\n".format(ds.nbytes / 1e9))
print(ds.info())

ds size in GB 379.06

xarray.Dataset {
dimensions:
    lat = 585 ;
    lon = 1386 ;
    time = 29219 ;

variables:
    float64 lat(lat) ;
        lat:long_name = latitude ;
        lat:standard_name = latitude ;
        lat:units = degrees_north ;
        lat:axis = Y ;
        lat:description = Latitude of the center of the grid cell ;
    float64 lon(lon) ;
    datetime64[ns] time(time) ;
        time:description = days since 1900-01-01 ;
    float32 TMax(time, lat, lon) ;
        TMax:units = C ;
    float32 TMin(time, lat, lon) ;
        TMin:units = C ;
    float32 Rain(time, lat, lon) ;
        Rain:units = mm ;
    float32 SRAD(time, lat, lon) ;
        SRAD:units = MJ m**-2 ;

// global attributes:
}
```

Need to drop all the `nan` lat/lons, because this should reduce the file sizes.

I am trying something like:

```py
dd = ds.isel(lat=list_of_valid_lats, lon=list_of_valid_lons).to_dataframe()
dd.to_csv("testing_filename.csv.gz", index=False, compression="gzip")
```

This takes forever and often crashes my computer. I have also tried using `to_dask_dataframe()`

I have also tried:

```py
df = ds.isel(lat=0, lon=1049).to_dataframe().reset_index()
df.to_csv("testing_filename_csv.gz", index=False, compression="gzip")
```

This works but is really slow when there are over ~400,000 gridpoints.

I also need to repeat this for ~40 similar files.

Any thoughts or ideas to improve the performance would be appreciated?